# Lagrangian (Lagrange multiplier) in Navier-Stokes equations (steady incompresible)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

First: **Stokes problem** (abstract analysis).

Let $X$ and $M$ Hilbert spaces and $a:X\times X\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $b:X\times M\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ bilinear and bounded operators.

We consider the following variational problem:
Given $f\in H'$, *find $(u,p)\in H\times M$ such that:*

$(S)\left\lbrace\begin{matrix}a(u,v)+b(v,p)=f(v),\quad\forall v\in H\\
b(u,q)=0,\quad \forall q\in M\end{matrix}\right.$

It is well known that under adequate hypotheses it is possible formulate the Problem $(S)$ in term of optimization problem. For example, defining
$J:X\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $L:X\times M\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as

$\begin{matrix}J(v)=(1/2)a(v,v)-f(v),\\
L(v,q)=J(v)+b(v,q)\end{matrix}$

=======================

Now we consider the problem (**steady incompresible Navier Stokes equations**): *Find $(u,p)\in H_0^1(\Omega)\times L^2(\Omega$) such that:*

$(NS)\left\lbrace\begin{matrix}\int_\Omega\nabla u\cdot\nabla v+\int_\Omega p\,\textrm{div}v+\int_\Omega (\nabla u)u\cdot v=\int_\Omega f\cdot v\qquad\forall v\in H_0^1(\Omega)\\
\int_\Omega q\,\textrm{div}v=0\quad\forall q\in L^2(\Omega)\end{matrix}\right.$

where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R^n}$ bounded ($n=2$ or $n=3$).
My question is:

for $(NS)$, which is the operators $J$ and $L$ ?

Thanks.